# Understanding combinators

Tags: scala

I have a question about combinators from book FPiS on the 84.

```
object RNG {

  type Rand[+A] = RNG => (A, RNG)
}

val int: Rand[Int] = _.nextInt
```

How do I interpret `type Rand[+A] = RNG => (A, RNG)`, and what does the underline by `_.nextInt` mean?

Comment: If you have 2 questions, it would be much better to ask 2 questions instead of 1 question. In particular, your second question has been asked and answered more than a dozen times already on [so].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`type` definitions are type aliases. This means you can replace `Rand[A]` wherever you see it by `RNG => (A, RNG)`. So for instance, `Rand[Int] = RNG => (Int, RNG)`.

Now, since we know `int` is a function that takes an `RNG`, we can define it as an anonymous function, such as `(r: RNG) => r.nextInt` (you'll probably see the definition for `nextInt` in the `RNG` trait). The `_` is a placeholder that does exactly the same thing, without having to name the parameter.